# a possibly stronger type of attack on identity-based encryption

Tags: security-definition, identity-based-encryption

What is known about the security of [identity-based encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity-based_encryption) schemes against attacks that involve seeing multiple ciphertexts and then receiving the private keys corresponding to *some* of those ciphertexts?

For example, is it known that feasible adversaries will have a negligible (in the security parameter $k$) probability of succeeding in the following, for IND-CCA2 IBE schemes?

- Challenger generates $\:\langle$pub,msk$\rangle\:$ and then gives $\:$pub$\:$ to $\mathcal{A}$
- $\mathcal{A}$ outputs a list of $\:(2\hspace{-0.03 in}\cdot\hspace{-0.03 in}k)\hspace{-0.01 in}+\hspace{-0.02 in}1\:$ distinct IDs
- Challenger chooses $\:x\in \{0,\hspace{-0.04 in}1\}^k\:$ uniformly
- Challenger computes $\:(2\hspace{-0.03 in}\cdot\hspace{-0.03 in}k)\hspace{-0.01 in}+\hspace{-0.02 in}1\:$ [Shamir shares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing) of $x$ so that one needs $\:k\hspace{-0.03 in}+\hspace{-0.04 in}1\:$ of them to recover $x$
- Challenger encrypts those shares using $\:$pub$\:$ and the corresponding IDs from the list provided by $\mathcal{A}$
- Challenger gives the resulting list of ciphertexts to $\mathcal{A}$
  $\mathcal{A}$ outputs a list of $k$ IDs
- Challenger uses $\:\langle$pub,msk$\rangle\:$ to extract the private decryption keys for those IDs
- Challenger gives the corresponding list of private decryption keys to $\mathcal{A}$ 
  $\mathcal{A}$ outputs $y$
  $\mathcal{A}$ succeeds if and only if $y = x$

Comment: I don't see how $\mathcal{A}$ could ever succeed in this case as it can only recover $k$ of the shares of $x$. Are you asking if it is known that with IBE, $\mathcal{A}$ cannot use private keys that correspond to some IDs to generate a private key that corresponds to a different ID?

Comment: Minor typo: Challenger gives pub (not msk) to adversary.

Comment: @minar: fixed </embarrased>

Comment: @mikeazo: $\;\;$ I'm asking if it can be important that $\mathcal{A}$ gets to choose which private keys to see _after_ seeing the ciphertexts. $\:$ I can see the reduction for the modification where the adversary must choose which private keys it will get before seeing the ciphertexts. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: I've not read it, but judging by the title this paper seems to address this exact situation: Bellare, Waters, Yilek: [Identity-Based Encryption Secure against Selective Opening Attack](http://eprint.iacr.org/2010/159).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably prove the security against your game from the security in the IND-ID-CCA game of Boneh and Franklin (see http://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs6204/Privacy-Security/Papers/Crypto/IBE-Weil-Pairing.pdf). The idea is to create an adversary $\mathcal{B}$ against IND-ID-CCA from your adversary $\mathcal{A}$. Essentially $\mathcal{B}$ will play man-in-the-middle between the IND-ID-CCA challenger and $\mathcal{A}$.

When $\mathcal{B}$ receives the $2k+1$ identities from $\mathcal{A}$, he chooses one of those at random (let's call it $ID_0$) sends two random values $(x_0,x_0')$ together with $ID_0$ to the challenger and receives an encryption $C_0$ of either $x_0$ or $x'_0$. For each of the other identities $ID_i$, $\mathcal{B}$ encrypts values $x_i$ chosen in such a way that $(x_0,\cdots, x_{2k+1})$ are valid shares for the secret sharing, the ciphertexts are denoted by $C_i$. Then $\mathcal{B}$ returns the ciphertexts to $\mathcal{A}$. [Note that if the challenger has chosen $x_0$ your game is perfectly emulated, otherwise, the shares are invalid]

When $\mathcal{A}$ sends the $k$ identities, if $ID_0$ is in the set $\mathcal{B}$ aborts the communication with $\mathcal{A}$ and returns a random guess to the challenger. Otherwise, $\mathcal{B}$ asks the $k$ keys to the challenger and sends those to $\mathcal{A}$. When $\mathcal{A}$ returns $y$, $\mathcal{B}$ proceeds as follow:
If $y$ is consistent with the share $x_0$, then $\mathcal{B}$ guesses that the challenger returned an encryption of $x_0$, otherwise $\mathcal{B}$ guesses at random.

If $\mathcal{A}$ wins your game with probability $\epsilon$, the advantage of $\mathcal{B}$ is approximately $\epsilon/4$.

---

Additional information:

1. The advantage is not $\epsilon/2$ as I wrote initially but $\epsilon/4$, this is due to the fact that there are two possible definitions for the advantage of a distinguisher. Some papers use the absolute value of the difference to $1/2$ and some papers use twice that. For technical reasons, twice the difference is preferable and I did not initialy noticed that Boneh-Franklin don't use this version.
2. How is the advantage computed ? This needs an additional hypothesis which I did not mention. Take your game with a variable number of shares, say $\ell$, keeping $k$ fixed and denote by $\ell_0$ the smallest value for which there exists an adversary with non-negligible advantage. Clearly, if there exists an adversary for $\ell=2k+1$ then $\ell_0\leq 2k+1$. And, of course, $\ell_0>k$ because with $k$ shares you have no information about $x$.

   If $\ell_0=2k+1$ use the above reasoning. in this case, $\mathcal{A}$ cannot return $y=x$ with non-negligible probability when one share contains $x'_0$ because you could then transform $\mathcal{A}$ into an adversary against $\ell_0-1$ shares by just adding a random valued share. If $\ell_0<2k+1$, redo the reasoning with the new $\ell_0$. This changes the advantage to $\frac{(\ell_0-k)\epsilon}{2k}$. The only problem is that in the case $\ell_0=k+1$, the reduction is not tight.

---

*Response to Ricky's comment on the tightness of the reduction:*

I don't see how you get a degradation exponential in $k$. Here is a more precise analysis of the full game if you don't assume that the probability of success jumps from negligible for non-negligible but do a more precise analysis.

Let $\epsilon_\ell$ be the best possible advantage for an adversary that wins your game with $\ell$ queries. Note that $\epsilon_\ell$ form an increasing sequence.

Moreover, the advantage in your original game is:
$$
\epsilon=\epsilon_{2k+1}=\sum_{i=k+1}^{2k+1}\epsilon_i-\epsilon_{i-1}.
$$
As a consequence, at least one of the differences is bigger than $\epsilon/(k+1)$.

Run $\mathcal{A}$ for an $\ell_0$ such that $\epsilon_{\ell_0}-\epsilon_{\ell_0-1}$ is not too small. The probability that $\mathcal{A}$ wins with $\ell_0$ genuine shares is higher than the probability with a fake share by at least  $\epsilon_{\ell_0}-\epsilon_{\ell_0-1}$, otherwise $\mathcal{A}$ could be used to improve $\epsilon_{\ell_0-1}$.

As a consequence, $\mathcal{B}$ wins with advantage at least $\frac{(\ell_0-k)(\epsilon_{\ell_0}-\epsilon_{\ell_0-1})}{2k}\geq \frac{(\ell_0-k)\epsilon}{2k^2}$.

So the degradation is polynomial in $k$ not exponential.

Comment: I don't see a reason it should be unlikely for $y$ to be consistent with $x_0$ when $\hspace{2 in}$ the Challenger returned an encryption of $x_0'$. $\:$

Comment: @RickyDemer Added explanation to address your question.

Comment: I just noticed a problem with your argument: in the asymptotic case, it's not clear that one _can_ choose a smallest $\ell$ since whether or not there is an adversary with a non-negligible success probability depends on all values of the function $\ell$, and in the concrete case, the reduction from $\:(2\cdot k)+1\:$ to $\:k+1\:$ changes $\epsilon$ by an exponential (in $k$) factor. $\;\;\;$

Comment: The more precise analysis does seem to work, since it uses the difference between the $\epsilon\hspace{.015 in}$s, $\hspace{.7 in}$ rather that just each $\epsilon$ individually. $\:$